# Problem loading rviz config file

Tags: ros2, rviz, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I don't understand why I cannot load the config file for RVIZ automatically using a python script.

The script is the following:

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch                      import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions              import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions        import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions          import Node


def generate_launch_description():

    config_file_name = 'config_file.rviz'

    print("Loading RVIZ config file: {}".format(config_file_name))

    rviz_config = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('HHH'), config_file_name)

    return LaunchDescription([DeclareLaunchArgument('use_sim_time',
                                                    default_value = 'false',
                                                    description   = 'Use simulation clock if true'),

                              Node(package    = 'rviz2',
                                   executable = 'rviz2',
                                   name       = 'rviz2',
                                   output     = 'screen',
                                   arguments  = ['-d', rviz_config]),
                              ])
```

the file config_file.rviz is stored in the package directory under config:

```
'package_name'
-> /config
    --> config_file.rviz
    --> params.yaml
-> /urdf
    --> urdf_model.xml
-> /'package_name'
    -->  publisher_node.py
```

starting the node with:

```
ros2 launch HHH launch_rviz.py
```

RVIZ starts, but it doesn't load the config file automatically as expected.

I compile the package with:

```
colcon build 'package_name'
```

or

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

but it doesn't copy my config file into the `share` directory under `install`.

What's wrong?

Thx!

PS: moving the config file into share manually fixes the issue. But it get "resetted" from time to time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382603/problem-loading-rviz-config-file/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2021-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed this problem by simpling leaving the config file `config_file.rviz` where it is in the package directory.

I then changed the `setup.py` where it searchs for the config file **in the package directory** (using `glob` and `path`) and **not** in the install direcory.

`colcon` doesn't work properly. Sometimes I realize that I need to delete all the folders **install**, **build** and **log** because `colcon` keeps old codes there without taking the new changes...

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2021-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0